# picking one of the value of foreach values

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

This code returns 7 values. I just want to retrieve the 7th value.

Could you give me some advice?

```
var a_nodes = root.Descendants("type");
foreach (var a_node in a_nodes)
{                          
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", a_node.GetAttributeValue("value", ""));
}
```

Comment: `root.Descendants("type").Last()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
root.Descendants("type").Last()
```

Or:

```
root.Descendants("type").Skip(6).First();
```

Comment: im getting this error :An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Answer (score 1):

Seventh node

```
var lastnode = root.Descendants("type").Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

If a_nodes implements `IEnumerable<T>` then you can call the Last extension method on it to get the last item in the list.  If it implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` then you can call Cast before Last.  If there may not be any items in the list then you should call LastOrDefault instead.

If you don't want to use LINQ or can't and a_nodes implements IList then you can get the Count and then the item at the index 1 less than that.